# I can't find why this security error shows up in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using springboot and try to send data from payment.html to payChek.html using controller.

when getting into payChek.html,

`org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String "//"`

this error shows up and I did not use '//' in controller

this is code I used to go to payChek.html

`mav.setViewName("payment/payChek");`

I need to know why the error shows up

I looked up where I put the link

```
mav.setViewName("payment/payChek");
```

but I have no clue what the problem is

Comment: Please add enough of your project to the question so we can reproduce.